# Why does this ansible local_action "ls" task fail?

Tags: ansible

The following task works:

```
  - name: capture bundle file name
    become: no
    local_action: "command ls {{playbook_dir}}/build/"
    register: BUNDLE_FILE_NAME
```

the list of files in ./build is assigned to BUNDLE_FILE_NAME

Stragely, the following does NOT work:

```
  - name: capture bundle file name
    become: no
    local_action: "command ls {{playbook_dir}}/build/*.js"
    register: BUNDLE_FILE_NAME
```

I get the error:

```
 ls: cannot access 'build/*.js': No such file or directory
```

which contradicts the fact that the first command runs successfully, the directory *is* accessible, and a file does natch *.js...

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use `shell` instead of `command`.

The `command` module does not do wildcards.